# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S3 with 4.3 run so slow?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean

I live in South Africa and we recently received the 4.3 update for the Galaxy S3. When I  perform general functions on the phone (open apps, browse web, run multiple apps), everything goes very slow. As an example, if I push the home button, the apps on my home screen are gone and then return again after a while.

Why would this update do this to my phone? How can I increase the performance of my device which now runs on 4.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the update not being done on a clean install. Also Samsung phones have TouchWiz overlay on android which is a bit heavy.

To make your phone fast do a full factory reset after taking a full data backup so that you can restore everything! Doing this would clean up any mess left behind by the update process.
Always try and do a clean install for a major update.

Comment: If I do a backup does it keep all apps along with their data and will I have to download 4.3 again for can I just do a reset on the current version?

Comment: for the apps get Titanium Backup.

Comment: Can confirm. Just did a factory reset on my S3 that was running slow and manually reinstalled everything. Device is still 4.3.
Wow. Much speed. Such faster.

Comment: it will just get really slow again after you install some stuff, I'm starting to think it was just a bad architecture of Android, any phone when you install some background running apps gets really slow.

Comment: I will agree, the reason this happens is because all the big players dont add an overlay on the android code rather they modify the core android framework code itself to help with the company apps! This in turn affects every app

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things but I have found a cause of the problem.

The RAM on the phone was full. My carrier is T-Mobile, There is a free app, T-Mobile My Account, which has a tab Device Health. Click it, you will find `Device Performance --> Show all tests -->RAM Usage --> Memory Boost` (tab to clear all RAM usage).

Give it a try! My two-year-old phone is back to life again.

Answer (score 0):

Every time another app start running, more of the phone's RAM is used, if too many apps are t=running, the phone will slow down... Get a RAM optimizer like Memory Booster.    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.memorybooster.lite&hl=en   Works for me, I have it on all of my Androids...